# forEach is not a function even with JSON.parse

Tags: javascript, json

I am having trouble with looping JSON data. I always get the error data.forEach is not a function even do i use JSON.parse. Anyone know how to fix this problem ?

```
 function getApiGebruiker() {
    CallWebAPI();
    //nieuw deel
    var url = "http://localhost:8081/persoons";

    //do get request
    var client = new HttpClient();
    client.get("http://myIPadress/persoons", function (response) {
      // do something with response
      var data = JSON.parse(response);
      console.log(data);
      //data = JSON.parse(data);
      let string = document.getElementById("pwd").value;
      let loginn = document.getElementById("login").value;
      data.forEach((persoons) => {
        console.log(persoons.gebruikersnaam);
      });
    });
```

Comment: Well an Object does not have forEach

Comment: Please try this `data._embedded.persoons.forEach(persoons => {`

Comment: Please don't post images of code or error messages. Copy the relevant code using the copy-paste functionality provided by your OS and paste it into the question between two lines that contain only `\`\`\``. Half of the picture you posted contains garbage and it is not clear what of the data structures displayed in it is `data`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `data` seems to be an object (`{}`) and not an array (`[]`).

Try:

```js
var data = JSON.parse(response);
var people = data._embedded.persoons

people.forEach((persoon) => {
  console.log(persoon.gebruikersnaam);
});
```